# I don't understand why my verification middleware behaves this way

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, middleware

In the last comparison block, I am comparing if the user.rol_id is not equal to the id of the role, the strange thing is that it should be the opposite according to the logic, so, I appreciate any explanation of what is happening in that comparison.

```
export function verifyRol(rol: string){
    return async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        const id = res.locals.jwtPayload.id;
        let user, rolModel;
        try {
            user = await User.findById(id);
            if (!user) return res.status(404).json({message: 'No se encuentra el usuario'});

            rolModel = await Rol.findOne({type_user: 1, name: rol});
            if (!rolModel) return res.status(404).json({message: 'No se encuentra el rol'});


            if (user.rol_id !== rolModel._id) {
                console.log(':O');
                next();
            }else {
                return res.status(401).json({message: 'No se encuentra autorizado'});
            }

        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(401).json({message: 'No se encuentra autorizado'});
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using TypeScript with NodeJS and MongoDB

Comment: what is supposed to happen when the two id values match or do not match?

Comment: Please don't just post and disappear.  Your best chance for help comes from the first people who engage and if you are not around, people go on to other things and others see a lack of engagement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you state yourself, you are doing the opposite of what you want. In addition, MongoDB returns ids as `ObjectId` instead of `string`, so equality check will always return `false`. If both objects are `ObjectId`, you should use the [`.equals` method](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#equals):

```
// If user has not the required role, throw a 401
if (!user.rol_id.equals(rolModel._id)) {
    return res.status(401).json({message: 'No se encuentra autorizado'});
// Else, continue to the next middleware
} else {
    console.log(':O');
    next();
}
```

Otherwise, you can cast the `ObjectId` into a string:

```
if (rolMode._id.toString() !== user.rol_id)
```

Comment: only pass the comparison block when the rolModel._id is different, doesn't work if is iqual.

Comment: Ok, I get it, we are comparing MongoDB `ObjectId` here. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the understandable and clear answer, 
now I understand much better how mongodb works.

Comment: Glad to help! You can accept and upvote the answer so that future readers know that it’s correct.